# Unable to send notification from Firebase Java application to mobile app thru Proxy

Tags: java, android, firebase, proxy

I build 2 apps one for mobile phone (Android) that receives notifications with Firebase and another in Java (desktop) from which i send the notifications. The app works very well but I need to move it to a computer that is behind a proxy. How can I bypass the proxy ?

This is what I`ve tried:

```
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "xxx");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "1212");
    System.setProperty("com.google.api.client.should_use_proxy","true");

     String PROXY_HOST = System.getProperty("https.proxyHost");
     int PROXY_PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("https.proxyPort"));
     Boolean PROXY_ENABLED = 
     Boolean.parseBoolean(System.getProperty("com.google.api.client.should_use_proxy", "false"));

     ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
     if (PROXY_ENABLED) {
     InetSocketAddress proxySocket = new InetSocketAddress(PROXY_HOST, PROXY_PORT);
     p.addFirst(new HttpProxyHandler(proxySocket));
     }
     //p.addLast(sslContext.newHandler(ch.alloc(), uri.getHost(), port));
    //p.addLast(new HttpClientCodec(), new HttpObjectAggregator(32 * 1024), channelHandler);
```

This doesn`t work. Can please someone give me an example that works so I can send notifications from behind the proxy ?

Thanks and have a nice day